# Store User Settings in ASP.NET Core Identity AspNetUsers Table or Not

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm setting up a web application using ASP.NET Core with authentication through Identity Framework. Quick question. I'm storing all kinds of data about the user like their address, account settings, subscription status and expiration date, etc. Am I better to store all that in the AspNetUsers table by creating ApplicationUser class inheriting IdentityUser, or should I keep that table for login/security information and create another table to store data only related to my application, and have a 1-to-1 relationship between the 2 tables?

Comment: Something also to consider is GDPR. I like to keep User provided data separate from data about the user collected via other means separate. This way, when/if your user chooses to delete all their info, they only delete the info they have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always a separate table/class.

Complexity grows with the application.  The table will become too large then you would spend time moving away from this.  We have similar in our legacy application with an Organisation that has grown to 70+ columns.  I've heard stories on Twitter about people with similar experiences.

Also alongside this you can think about Single Responsibility.  Given a single reason for change - or more to Uncle Bobs updated definition `"A module should be responsible to one, and only one, actor"`.

You could end up having settings per `module` - and the more you add, this is just going to get bigger.  Sure, just leave it till later to change things - but this never happens.

For me the Identity is its own system.  Not your system.  It provides a mechanism to authenticate.  It uses most columns in the able or fields in the user class to do this.

Your settings is about your application - this is your domain.  If you replace `Identity`, you might replace that user table/user class.  Then where will your settings end up?

Comment: As I'm moving the fields from ApplicationUser to Customer, something else I'm realizing: not all users are customers! My admin account doesn't need customer info.